# Eloquent relationship morphOne strange behavior. Can store but cannot retrieve

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

My profile class has the following functions:

```
public function documents()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\File', 'entity')
        ->where('type', 'document');
}

public function avatar()
{
    return $this->morphOne('App\File', 'entity')
        ->where('type', 'avatar');
}
```

I can store and retrieve the documents with no issues. To get the documents I use:

```
$profile->documents
```

Avatar is being stored with

```
 $avatar = new File([
            "type" => 'avatar',
            "link" => $link,
        ]);
 $profile->avatar()->save($avatar);
```

I can get the avatar with

```
$profile->avatar()->first()
```

but not with

```
$profile->avatar
```

it returns null.

What might be the issue?

Laravel version: 5.5.35

PHP 7.0.24-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Sep 28 2017 16:20:59) ( NTS )

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.21, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Comment: are you eager loading it (e.g. `Profile::with('avatar')->...`)?

Comment: nope. Neither I eager load the ```documents```, but it works

Comment: It's interesting. If there's only one avatar then you may need to just store the file id on the profile table instead since `morphOne` will probably be looking for it there anyway.

Comment: Issue resolved. Silly mistake. The ```profile``` table had column ```avatar``` that, by some reason, was not deleted through migration.